# R tidytext graph comes up vertical and not horizontal

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidytext

I'm trying to create a sentiment analysis using the [tidytext code here](https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html) but my graph comes out vertical, without the output making sense compared to the original which is horizontal. How can I fix this?

```
#Unnest tokens
edAItext = edAI %>% select(Group, Participant_ID, Brainscape_Pattern) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, Brainscape_Pattern)

# Inner join
bing_word_counts <- edAItextTest %>%
   inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>%
   count(word, sentiment, sort = TRUE) %>%
   ungroup()

#Check
 bing_word_counts

#Plot
 bing_word_counts %>%
   group_by(sentiment) %>%
   slice_max(n, n = 5) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(n, word, fill = sentiment)) +
   geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
   facet_wrap(~sentiment, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = "Contribution to sentiment",
        y = NULL)

This is how it looks:
```

[image: My sentiment analysis]

This is how it's supposed to look:

[image: Proper graph]

Comment: Have you tried `geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, orientation = "y")`?

Comment: I have, and it doesn't make a difference unfortunately. The graph still looks the same.

Comment: What about `coord_flip()`?

Comment: It flips the graph but the bars are still in the wrong place.

Comment: can you share more of your data? or reproduce using R data set? The tidytext instructions work just fine, so I suspect the error is being caused with the edAItext or the edAItextTest input.

Comment: I would also make sure that you have an updated version of ggplot2.